# request.body is empty even though payload is sent across

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a PUT endpoint which receives a payload and coverts it to an object using `[FromBody]`.

This works fine when running on localhost (using IIS Express).

But when I run it via the production server (IIS), it fails. The validation error is:

```
{
    "": [
        "A non-empty request body is required."
    ]
}
```

I can recreate this with both my client code and using Postman.

Thinking that maybe the payload was malformed, I used some middleware (posted elsewhere on Stack Overflow) to inspect the body before it reached the endpoint (see code below), but even at that stage the request.body is empty.

I can't see any other places where the request has already been read at this stage (as I appreciate that can clear it).

I've read countless Stack Overflow posts and other web pages, and nothing else seems to come close to this situation (where request.body is empty, even though you can see in the client the payload is sent).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm happy to provide any further details.

For reference, here is the code.

### Payload

```
{"currentlySaved":false,"type":"album"}
```

### End point

```
        // PUT api/<controller>/toggleSaveState
        [HttpPut("toggleSaveState/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Put(string id, [FromBody] ToggleSaveStateRequest requestDetails)
        {
            ...
        }
```

The object representing the payload:

```
    public class ToggleSaveStateRequest
    {
        public bool CurrentlySaved { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

### Middleware used to check the request.body

Note: the problem takes place whether I include this middleware or not. I've included it in a bid to diagnose the problem.

```
    public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            //First, get the incoming request
            var request = await FormatRequest(context.Request);
            Console.WriteLine($"REQUEST: {request}");

            //Copy a pointer to the original response body stream
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

            //Create a new memory stream...
            using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //...and use that for the temporary response body
                context.Response.Body = responseBody;

                //Continue down the Middleware pipeline, eventually returning to this class
                await _next(context);

                //Format the response from the server
                var response = await FormatResponse(context.Response);

                //TODO: Save log to chosen datastore
                Console.WriteLine($"RESPONSE: {response}");

                //Copy the contents of the new memory stream (which contains the response) to the original stream, which is then returned to the client.
                await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            var body = request.Body;

            //This line allows us to set the reader for the request back at the beginning of its stream.
            request.EnableRewind();

            //We now need to read the request stream.  First, we create a new byte[] with the same length as the request stream...
            var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];

            //...Then we copy the entire request stream into the new buffer.
            await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            //We convert the byte[] into a string using UTF8 encoding...
            var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

            //..and finally, assign the read body back to the request body, which is allowed because of EnableRewind()
            request.Body = body;

            return $"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString} {bodyAsText}";
        }

        private async Task<string> FormatResponse(HttpResponse response)
        {
            //We need to read the response stream from the beginning...
            response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            //...and copy it into a string
            string text = await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            //We need to reset the reader for the response so that the client can read it.
            response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            //Return the string for the response, including the status code (e.g. 200, 404, 401, etc.)
            return $"{response.StatusCode}: {text}";
        }
    }
```

---

Edit:

### Version of endpoint without the `[FromBody]`:

The following is here to try and simplify my explanation.

```
// PUT api/<controller>/toggleSaveState
[HttpPut("toggleSaveState/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(string id)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("body", body);
    }
    ...
    return Ok();
}
```

Given the above endpoint (with no middleware in place), when it's run locally, `body` has the value of:

```
{"currentlySaved":false,"type":"album"}
```

However, when it is run remotely, it is empty.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with PUT? Make sure it's enabled on IIS. You could also change it to POST and see if it will work.

Comment: @Krzysztof-Cieslinski: Interesting! Post does work. I'd still like to get PUT working if possible. As far as I can tell PUT is enabled on IIS, but I'll dig a little deeper into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is here:

```
            //Copy a pointer to the original response body stream
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
```

You are assigning a reference to the response stream, and then you are overwriting(that stream) it with an empty memory stream here:

```
                //...and use that for the temporary response body
                context.Response.Body = responseBody;
```

So the reference in `originalBodyStream` variable, is now pointing to that empty stream as well. Other words - at this point the content of `context.Response.Body` is lost.
If you want to copy the request body stream to the other stream, use below:

```
await context.Response.Body.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
```

Remember that streams are reference type so this:

```
var bodyVar = request.Body;
```

assigns only a reference to the stream(not the value!) - other words any modifications on the `request.Body` will be reflected on the `bodyVar` as it points to the same place in memory.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you're saying. The problem is the following line (which comes before that) still displays an empty request body:

//First, get the incoming request
var request = await FormatRequest(context.Request);
Console.WriteLine($"REQUEST: {request}");

And just to avoid any possible confusion, even when I don't include this middleware, I still get the error message.

Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: That's because you have same type of mistake in FormatRequest method. You are assigning a reference here: var body = request.Body; and then you are  doing this request.Body = body;  what makes actually no sense. You could try to rewind that body stream by assigning its position to 0: request.Body.Position = 0;

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry I think the middleware is confusing things. Again, you make a valid point but unfortunately it isn't the problem. I've added a new example above (see 'Version of endpoint without the `[FromBody]`') which takes the middleware out of the equation and hopefully explains things better. Thanks again for your help.